# why a update-period value for kubernetes rolling-update should be long (default: 1m0s)?

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine

I was wondering what would be the potential problem if I reduce the --update-period (whose default value is 1m0s) to about 5s (or even 1s)? I've watched a few video clips, and it seems the presenters implied that it's a bad idea to have a short period but did not explain why.

The reason why I want to make it shorter is that we sometimes prefer fast and a little risky transition, rather than safe and steady one. As far as I know, what rolling-update does is:

```
while the goal has not been achieved {
  scale-up the new version
  sleep as specified by --update-period
  scale-down the old one
  check deadline
}
```

From the above flow, I don't see any problem of not sleeping for a long time. Deadline checking is based on the timeout configuration, and so, it seems the only outcome of changing the --update-period would be iterating the loop more frequently.

One thing I have not fully understood is how scaling down is performed, but I assume that it still does graceful termination, such as sending SIGTERM and waiting for 30s until finally sending SIGKILL to the processes in the pod.

FYI, I'm using the Google Container Engine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It **should** not be long, this is just a precaution in case a pod transitions to a Running state but crashes a couple of seconds later. If your update period is short, you'll keep deploying pods that are unstable eventually, and won't give the whole process enough time to notice.

If you're willing to take the risk it's totally fine to have a short update period.

Also, if you want true fast and reliable deployments you should check the Deployment API. The rolling update logic happens server side which increases the reliability and speed.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It seems to me that increasing max-surge can accelerate rolling-update; e.g., max-surge=100% would deploy the new pod as fast as possible. I guess max-unavailable=100% is optional but it prevents nodes from being overloaded. I'll read the relevant code and do some experiment, but it could be also much appreciated if you could shed some light on this. Thank you again.

Comment: If I wanted a super fast deployment where it's OK to run in a degraded mode I'd leave the max surge value to `1` and set max unavailable to `20%` or so. In that case old pods will get destroyed and replaced by new one almost immediately, except for the last 20% which will ensure the service is at least still responding. As you mentioned, the best is still to experiment and measure.